# Sending javascript files using Node server with NowJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, raphael, client-server, nowjs-sockets

This question should be simple to answer for anyone with Node experience -- unfortunately I am an extreme novice.

I am writing a web application for a board game that will use a server-client architecture to show real-time changes made to the board to all clients. The application uses Raphael to display the graphics.

I have created a server that successfully sends the HTML file to respond to any request, but the board does not display -- only the raw HTML without any Javascript comes up. I think it is because I have programmed the server to always respond with the HTML file, and I can't figure out how to send the Javascript files (client.js, raphael.js) to the client so that the page can load properly.

The relevant code is below. For now, I'm just trying to get the browser to draw one Raphael element so I can see that the client is properly getting the Javascript files it needs to load the page.

On the server side:

```
var fs = require('fs');
 var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, response){
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    response.write(data);
    response.end();
    });
});
```

On the client side:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var R = Raphael("container", 1000, 700);
    this.R.path("M0,0l1000,700").attr({"stroke-width": "5"});
});
```

You can assume that the HTML file is formatted correctly and includes references to all the JS files -- I've had the application working great without the server-client architecture for a while now. Also, I am using NowJS, so any solution that incorporates that framework would be welcome as well.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure why you want to send JavaScript files, why can't the files be read from the server directly the browser? You can send the HTML and reference the JavaScript in the script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your server side you are always returning index.html

check out how the createServer method is used in this gist: https://gist.github.com/1245922

it evaluates the extension to return a proper mime-type and then calls the stream file function to return the requested url/file from the fs.

if you're going to use this with nowjs then you'll want to also use along the lines of:

```
    var everyone = nowjs.initialize(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the static middleware

http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-static.html